# Modal disappears because of dependencies used?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Would tell me whether my Bootstrap modal disappears right after it shows because of these:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.2.0",
    "angular": "1.4.9",
    "angular-route": "1.4.9",
    "angular-cookies": "1.4.9",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.4",
    "moment": "2.11.2",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker":"4.17.37",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap-bower":"1.1.2",
    "noty":"2.3.7",
    "ng-grid":"3.1.1",
    "tr-ng-grid":"3.1.6"    
  }
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Is it error...? May b you have included `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap-modal.js,` and check you have included one version of bootstrap either `bootstrap.js` or `bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: No not because of that .. you need to do more coding to let it stay . and Remember bootstrap and angular seperate is a Time Consuming thing.take a look at it  it may helps .http://plnkr.co/edit/u9HHaRlHnko492WDtmRU?p=preview

Comment: I suggest https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ instead of Bootstrap .. that make life easy :-) Good Luck !!

Comment: Thank you all.. I excluded bootstrap.. although I had to change a lot of my project features but as you @N.V.Prasad said, life is better now.. :)